# Can I see input parameters in my metamask when I call a function?

Tags: metamask

When I use metamask to call a function on a UI, I can look at the data section of metamask to see the hex data, the address of the contract I'm interacting with, and the function I'm calling.

How do I get the parameters that are being inputted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by decoding the input data with sites like [this](https://lab.miguelmota.com/ethereum-input-data-decoder/example/). But you would need to find the ABI of the contract you are calling. IF the contract is an ERC20 token or any other standard token, a standard abi is sufficient.

You can find most ABIs via Etherscan when searching for the address of the contract you are calling.

Comment: This is perfect thank you. So to verify I'm actually calling the function I'm calling with the right parameters, I have to do this long process? It looks like `var inputs = ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder.decode(types, data);` is the main function in that code for decoding. Hm. Insightful. Thanks.